# My stepper motor works, but it shouldn't. Either the cables are mislabeled or the sequence is incorrect

Tags: raspberry-pi, stepper-motor, debugging, stepper-driver

I have a Nema 17 stepper motor and a [TB6612](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/TB6612FNG_datasheet_en_20121101.pdf) driver from Adafruit. To control this stepper motor I am using a Raspberry Pi. I cannot figure out which cables in my stepper correspond to which coils: the datasheet included with the stepper says that the BLK and GRN cables are from one coil, and the other two cables, RED and BLU, correspond to the other coil. This could be true since the resistance between these pairs of cables is around 30Ω.

Now, if I plug it that way to my driver (it has two outputs, one for each coil), the stepper only vibrates. I checked each possible way to plug the stepper and these are the 6 ways that actually worked:

1. BLK and RED to OUT1, GRN and BLU to OUT2
2. RED and GRN to OUT1, BLU and BLK to OUT2
3. GRN and BLU to OUT1, BLK and RED to OUT2
4. BLK and BLU to OUT1, GRN and RED to OUT2
5. RED and BLK to OUT1, BLU and GRN to OUT2
6. GRN and RED to OUT1, BLK and BLU to OUT2

The first three turn clockwise, the other three counterclockwise.

Just to make sure you have all the available information, I checked all the possible inputs for my driver, and got that these inputs yield the following outputs:

[0,1,1,1] --> [1,0,0,0]

[0,0,1,1] --> [1,1,0,0]

[1,0,1,1] --> [0,1,0,0]

[1,0,0,1] --> [0,1,1,0]

[1,1,0,1] --> [0,0,1,0]

[1,1,0,0] --> [0,0,1,1]

[1,1,1,0] --> [0,0,0,1]

[0,1,1,0] --> [1,0,0,1]

So that, for example, if I plug my stepper's cables such that BLK and RED are a pair, and GRN and BLU another one, if my driver's input is [0,1,1,0], it outputs [1,0,0,1], and therefore BLK is high, RED is low, GRN is low, and BLU is high.

Even though I figured out how to make my stepper turn correctly, I want to understand why is it working when the datasheet clearly states that BLK and GRN are a coil, and RED and BLU are another one.

**Additional Information**

If I change the input sequence, and thus having the following output:

[1,0,0,0] --> [0,1,1,1]

[1,1,0,0] --> [0,0,1,1]

[0,1,0,0] --> [1,0,1,1]

[0,1,1,0] --> [1,0,0,1]

[0,0,1,0] --> [1,1,0,1]

[0,0,1,1] --> [1,1,0,0]

[0,0,0,1] --> [1,1,1,0]

[1,0,0,1] --> [0,1,1,0]

I plug the stepper motor as if BLK and GRN were a coil and RED and BLU another one. Then My stepper motor turns but in a way that is clearly not desirable.

I will appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Links to the datasheets might be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Tyler, I don't have any link to the stepper datasheet, it is just half a paper that came with my motor. I'll add the link to the driver.

Comment: Perhaps you've checked the two stepper coils incompletely. Their DC resistance should be identical. And the resistance *between them* should be infinite. Resistance-to-shell should be infinite too. You can also step manually with a DC power supply, first into one coil, then into the other coil, then (reversed) into the first coil, then (reversed) into the other coil...etc.

Comment: @glen_geek, when I checked I got that two pairs of coils had a very similar DC resistance, and the resistance between them yielded very high values (in the order of mega ohms). So, I believe those are indeed the two coils.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coils **are as designated**, and you have to connect the "ends" of each coil to **opposing** output pins so that you can control the direction of the current, and thereby the direction the motor will turn.
When you put a hi on blk and a low on red, and a low on grn and a hi on blu, the motor will turn CW.  If you reverse this, it will turn CCW.

Additional information:
After further thought on this, I believe it should work the way you initially connected them (when it just vibrated), except you have to **reverse** the connections to **one** of the coils.